# Error sending email programmatically from non gmail account

Tags: java, android, email, authenticator

I'm trying to send and email programmatically from my Android app, using some known methods which I took from here.

The method is working fine with gmail account, but when I try with a different provider account like, hotmail, yahoo, outlook, it throws this error:

```
07-04 13:18:34.736: I/System.out(32140): ERROR SENDING MESSAGE: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp-mail.outlook.com, port: 587;
07-04 13:18:34.736: I/System.out(32140):   nested exception is:
07-04 13:18:34.736: I/System.out(32140):    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7912c980: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
07-04 13:18:34.736: I/System.out(32140): error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766 0x7387f7d0:0x00000000)
```

I'm using the following credentials to send the mail:

User: @hotmail.com
Host: smtp-mail.outlook.com
Port: 587

Tried with different accounts (all of them non gmail) and I get the same error every time.

My `MailSender` class is:

```
public class MailSender{

public synchronized static void sendMail(String[] dest, String org, String pass, String body, String port, String host){ 

    String[] to = dest;
    final String user = org;
    final String password = pass;
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);  

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", user);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);
        }
    });

    try{ 
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));     
        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[to.length]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) { 
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]); 
        } 
        message.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
        message.setSubject("Arcas Ollé Alarm Message");   
        BodyPart messageBody = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBody.setText(body);  
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBody);
        message.setContent(multipart ); 
        Transport.send(message); 
        System.out.println("MESSAGE SENT...");
    }catch (MessagingException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR SENDING MESSAGE: "+ ex);
    }
  }
}
```

And I call the method like:

```
MailSender.sendMail(dest, org, pass, body, port, host);
```

As I said before the method works fine with gmail account, so I don't think it is a data parsing problem, and I'm sure all the credentials I tried are correct.

It could be a proprieties problem.

So if anyone could help me solve this out, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,

margabro.

Comment: your host `smtp-mail.outlook.com Port: 587` is not reachable

Comment: I could also understand that. But I don't know where the issue is. Tell me another reachable host I could try... I have account almost everywhere. None is working except gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution (after a lot of research and testing). I post it as an answer in case someone else has the same problem.

In the mail sender class I made the following changes in the properties code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.user", user);
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
//props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

Added port 587 as socket factory port for all hosts and commented the line:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
```

The configs for the hosts I tested and used are:

**-- HOTMAIL / OUTLOOK --**

**HOST:** smtp.live.com
**PORT:** 25

**-- GMAIL --**

**HOST:** smtp.gmail.com
**PORT:** 587

**-- YAHOO! --**

**HOST:** smtp.mail.yahoo.com
**PORT:** 587

Hope it helps :)

Comment: your answer worked for me but while sending mail using yahoo i am getting this exception "10-09 11:23:26.891: I/System.out(11507): ERROR SENDING MESSAGE: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 554 Transaction failed :  Cannot send message due to possible abuse; please visit http://postmaster.yahoo.com/abuse_smtp.html for more information" Any idea about this ??

Answer (score 2):

For reference:

**Gmail- Host:** smtp.gmail.com , Port: 465

**Hotmail- Host:** smtp.live.com , Port: 587

**Yahoo- Host:** smtp.mail.yahoo.com , Port: 465

Comment: Thanks, it is working also with Yahoo, but not Hotmail. Any idea why?

Comment: Change to port: 25 unstead of Port: 587

Comment: It's weird how both Yahoo and Gmail hosts are pingable, but not Hotmail.

Answer (score 0):

Create your account in this site for testing purpose

### http://www.serversmtp.com/en/smtp-configuration

And did you try this settings using POP mail server ?

Hotmail/MSN

incoming mail server: pop3.live.com

Security type = SSL

Server port 995

---

outgoing mail server: smtp.live.com

login required = yes

security type = TLS

Server port 587